# Installing a malicious script on PC through PlayOnLinux , would that script be in ubuntu?

Tags: playonlinux

If It happen to install a program such as "paint" by PlayOnLinux and contain malicious script this script would be in linux or just in the virtual environment PlayOnLinux?
Just delete the PlayOnLinux folder and it all ok?

Every time will install a program by PlayOnLinux they warn:

`not responsible for these scripts`

2-Can I trust PlayOnLinux programs? Or until steam and SketchUp by PlayOnLinux are with a malicious script too?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a worrying **No.**

First off, it is wholly possible that viruses will look for WINE/PlayOnLinux and use these as a jumping point to get control over your system as a whole. Windows programs (if written properly) can detect if they're running in Wine.

Secondly, PlayOnLinux/Wine has a habit of "virtualizing" your Linux filesystem as a drive to the emulated Windows. If some malware (say, Cryptolocker) runs and targets these drives, your files stored within Ubuntu are also at risk. Now, you could block this risk by just disabling the ability for WINE to access Linux files, but then you're losing a key aspect of what makes WINE useful. Plus, a virus could still use Point 1 to pwn your system.

Now, unless you're installing/running untrusted code or prorams, you probably don't have anything to fear. Most software from the PlayOnLinux repos are typically vetted and are considered safe, but you still need to consider the fact that it is still possible for malware to infect *those* programs, infecting your computer in turn. There is still no better form of anti-virus than a smart (and slightly paranoid) user.

Even if you delete the PoL folder and any executable, the virus itself will be gone from your system, but any effects (like tampered Ubuntu files) will still persist.

Comment: thanks very much.What if I delete the source folder?

Comment: @41Den Added to my answer.